Powershell команда ping
Всем здраствуйте! Я учу докер и в powershell скачал и открыл контейнер docker run -it busybox далее попробовал нажать команду ping 8.8.8.8 и не знаю как её остановить. Что нажать подскажите, спасибо!


Ctrl+C? . . . .

Да!!! Спасибо, действительно помогло! Ctrl+C и произошла остановка
